# Browser extension testing with selenium c# in Saucelabs

Tags: c#, selenium, browser-extension, saucelabs

Is it possible to test browser extensions with selenium c# in **Saucelab**. If so how and where to place the latest extension package in **saucelab** VM so that selenium launches the browser with the extension.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox and chrome it is possible by providing capabilities or profile. For Example in case of firefox:

File file = new File("firebug-1.8.1.xpi");
   FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
   firefoxProfile.addExtension(file);
   firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.8.1"); // Avoid startup screen

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);